# Why do I get "response: 7:item Already Owned" error when I use in-app to test order?

Tags: android-studio, in-app-purchase

I test Google in-app order in my App, it's OK when I test it for the first time.

Then I open Google Play webpage ,and do a refund operation for the test order item, but I get the error `"Purchasing error: labResult: Unable to buy item (response: 7:item Already Owned)"` when I try to do a purchase operation again, how can I fix it?